# Python: Compare lists and combine in common fields

Tags: python, list

I have the following two lists:

```
ISO3166_CountryCodes_NO = [["NO","Norge"],["SE","Sverige"],["GR","Hellas"]]
ISO3166_CountryCodes_EN = [["NO","Norway"],["SE","Sweden"],["GR","Greece"]]
```

As you see, the country code is always the same, but the country name differs (different translations)
How can I create one list like this:

```
ISO3166_CountryCodes = [["NO","Norge","Norway"],["SE","Sverige","Sweden"],["GR","Hellas","Greece"]]
```

I could do it with a for loop in the first list, and for each element I could search into the second one to find the country code which is common. Then append the translations in a new list but I feel this way is somewhat clumsy.

Is there any better way to achieve this in Python? For example in Perl that I am more familiar with, I would use a hash table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, a dictionary is a hash table. First, create two dictionaries:

```
NO_dict = {x[0]: x[1] for x in ISO3166_CountryCodes_NO}
EN_dict = {x[0]: x[1] for x in ISO3166_CountryCodes_EN}
```

which gives you:

```
{'GR': 'Hellas', 'NO': 'Norge', 'SE': 'Sverige'}
{'GR': 'Greece', 'NO': 'Norway', 'SE': 'Sweden'}
```

You can then create a list like so:

```
final_list = [[k, NO_dict[k], EN_dict[k]] for k in NO_dict]
```

Giving you:

```
[['GR', 'Hellas', 'Greece'],
 ['SE', 'Sverige', 'Sweden'],
 ['NO', 'Norge', 'Norway']]
```

You might find it easier later to keep the data in a dictionary with the names stored in tuples, e.g.:

```
final_dict = {k:(NO_dict[k], EN_dict[k]) for k in NO_dict}
```

So that you can fetch the items using the abbreviation as a key e.g. `final_dict['NO']` would produce `('Norge', 'Norway')`

**EDIT: OrderedDict**

If you have python >= 2.7, and you are concerned about the order, you can still use dictionaries by using `OrderedDict`, for example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# A list of lists can be used as input for an OrderedDict, so don't need to loop
NO_dict = OrderedDict(ISO3166_CountryCodes_NO)
EN_dict = OrderedDict(ISO3166_CountryCodes_EN)

# Assumes you want the result in the same order as the Norwegian list
# Iterate over the English list if it has a preferred order

final_dict = OrderedDict([(k, (NO_dict[k], EN_dict[k])) for k in NO_dict])
```

(for another implementation see AshwiniChaudhary's answer)

Comment: Note that there are two differences between this answer and Ashwini's answer when it comes to the allowed input and resulting output: this solution works even if the order of the countries differs between lists, but it also (naturally) does not preserve this order in the solution.

Comment: @lazyr added a solution which preserves order as well as works even if the lists are randomly ordered.

Answer (score 2):

something like this, using `unique_everseen` from [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) and [`chain()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
In [26]: from itertools import *

In [27]: lis1=[["NO","Norge"],["SE","Sverige"],["GR","Hellas"]]

In [28]: lis2=[["NO","Norway"],["SE","Sweden"],["GR","Greece"]]

In [29]: from itertools import *

In [30]: def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
        seen = set()
        seen_add = seen.add
        if key is None:
                for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
                        seen_add(element)
                        yield element
                else:
                        for element in iterable:
                                k = key(element)
                                if k not in seen:
                                        seen_add(k)
                                        yield element
   ....:                         

In [31]: [list(unique_everseen(chain(*x))) for x in izip(lis1,lis2)]
Out[31]: 
[['NO', 'Norge', 'Norway'],
 ['SE', 'Sverige', 'Sweden'],
 ['GR', 'Hellas', 'Greece']]
```

**or:** you can use [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from itertools, combined with `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
In [42]: from operator import *

In [43]: [[k]+list(map(itemgetter(1),g)) for x in zip(lis1,lis2) for k,g in groupby(x,itemgetter(0))]
Out[43]: 
[['NO', 'Norge', 'Norway'],
 ['SE', 'Sverige', 'Sweden'],
 ['GR', 'Hellas', 'Greece']]
```

or using [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) , which is a subclass of `dict` and maintains order as well:

```
In [47]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [48]: dic=OrderedDict()

In [49]: for x in lis1:
   ....:     dic.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1])
   ....:     

In [50]: for x in lis2:
    dic.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1])
   ....:     

In [51]: dic
Out[51]: OrderedDict([('NO', ['Norge', 'Norway']), ('SE', ['Sverige', 'Sweden']), ('GR', ['Hellas', 'Greece'])])

In [52]: [[x]+y for x,y in dic.items()]
Out[52]: 
[['NO', 'Norge', 'Norway'],
 ['SE', 'Sverige', 'Sweden'],
 ['GR', 'Hellas', 'Greece']]

#or directly access the names using the short-name
In [53]: dic['NO']
Out[53]: ['Norge', 'Norway']

In [54]: dic['GR']
Out[54]: ['Hellas', 'Greece']
```

Comment: @VangelisTasoulas You're welcome, you can either upvote or mark the answer as accepted if you find it helpful, I think that's the correct way of saying "thanks" on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension :

```
>>> [[s]+
     [n for (c,n) in ISO3166_CountryCodes_NO if c==s]+
     [n for (c,n) in ISO3166_CountryCodes_EN if c==s]
     for s in set([c for (c,n) in ISO3166_CountryCodes_NO] + 
                  [c for (c,n) in ISO3166_CountryCodes_EN])]

[['GR', 'Hellas', 'Greece'], ['SE', 'Sverige', 'Sweden'], ['NO', 'Norge', 'Norway']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3.2.

1st way:

```
[[i[0],i[1],v[1]] for i in list1 for v in list2  if i[0]==v[0]]
```

2nd way:

```
res=[]
for i,v in list(zip(list1,list2):
    tem=[i[0]]
    if i[0]==v[0]: tem.extend([i[1],v[1]])
res.append(tem)
```

Comment: Please use code formatting only for the code segments and not for your whole answer. For more formatting options, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help